Tags page looks weird when there are no search results
On the Tags page, when there are no search results (e.g. if you search for test2), the tag list shrinks, but there's still a white ribbon visible in the footer, giving the page a really weird look:

On closer look, there seems to be a problem with the ribbon on all pages, because it's one pixel on each side wider than the main content box.

Tested on three browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) on macOS.

I can confirm this. Related bug also affects mobile browsers.
In fact, this could point to more than just a single pixel problem since the whole flow seems to be a bit broken.
For example, here's the latest Chrome on Android (which used to be displayed flawlessly before)…
all tags



notice the bottom right glitch (zoomed in)



tag search results



